# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'author_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.8

I'm actually new to Laravel Framework. Have been trying to post to the Mysql Database, I was getting an error on my Author_id.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'author_id' doesn't have a default value.

Have checked everywhere but all efforts were proven abortive

Here is the Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //$table->engine = “InnoDB”;

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('author_id')->unique()->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->text('excerpt');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();   
        $table->timestamps();
    });



}
```

Here is my  create.blade.php:

```
 <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box">
              <div class="box-body">

              {!! Form::model($post, [
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'url'  => 'backend/blog'
              ]) !!}  

             {{-- <form method="POST" action="{{ url('blog/store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf  --}}

                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('title') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                        @if($errors->has('title'))
                        <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('title') }} </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('slug') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                      {!! Form::label('slug') !!}
                      {!! Form::text('slug', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}

                      @if($errors->has('slug'))
                      <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('slug') }} </span>
                      @endif
                      </div>

                        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('excerpt') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                          {!! Form::label('excerpt') !!}
                          {!! Form::textarea('excerpt', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}

                        @if($errors->has('excerpt'))
                        <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('excerpt') }} </span>
                        @endif

                        </div>

                            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('body') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                              {!! Form::label('body') !!}
                              {!! Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}

                        @if($errors->has('body'))
                        <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('body') }} </span>
                        @endif
                            </div>

                          <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('published_at') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                            {!! Form::label('published_at', 'Published Date') !!}
                            {!! Form::text('published_at', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s'])!!}

                            @if($errors->has('published_at'))
                            <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('published_at') }} </span>
                            @endif
                            </div>

                        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('category_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                          {!! Form::label('category_id', 'Category') !!}
                          {!! Form::select('category_id', App\Category::pluck('title', 'id'), null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Choose category' ]) !!}

                          @if($errors->has('category_id'))
                          <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('category_id') }} </span>
                          @endif
                        </div>

                        <hr>

                        {!! Form::submit('Create new post', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
          </div>
        </div>
      <!-- ./row -->
    </section>
```

Here is my Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model
```

{

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'excerpt', 'body', 'user_id', 'published_at', 'category_id'];
protected $dates = ['published_at'];

public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::Class);
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
// images path
Public function getImageUrlAttribute($Value)
{
    $imageUrl = "";

if ( ! is_null($this->image))
{
    $imagePath = public_path(). "/img/" . $this->image;
    if (file_exists($imagePath)) $imageUrl = asset("img/" . $this->image);
}
return $imageUrl;
```

}

Comment: You must add nullable() function like this. $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

Comment: This error means that you are not filling with data the `author_id`. Also this field is missing from your  `$fillable` array or you must specify this field as nullable on your migration.

Comment: Yes I know I wasn't filling it, even when I added it to my fillable, I still get the same error. Im new to Laravel Nerea, Please guide me thanks. Under which page should I add that Safak Ciplak?

Comment: You must relate the post you create with a specific user (aka author). Else set the author_id column to be nullable but this is not what you would want since posts have authors

Comment: Very correct at Nikos M. Nullable is not the best option in this Case. Author must be responsible for every post published. Would really appreciate if you can help me. this stage has really consumed so much of my time. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For example to associate a Post to the current user (eg inside a controller method that saves the Post to db) do sth like the following:

```
// controller method
public function savePost( Request $request )
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        // your validation rules here..
        ]);
    $post = new Post(); // from Post model
    $post->fill($data);
    $post->author()->associate(\Auth::user()); // relate post to current user
    $post->save(); // save to db
    return view('whatever_your_view_is', []);
}
```

If you need more information leave a comment

In `Post` model make the following change:

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::Class, 'author_id'); // specify the column which stores the author in posts table
}
```

See [documentation on defining relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

Comment: I cannot thank you enough at Nikos M...I noticed is now saving into the table but give me this error, SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `slug`, ..But I don't have any column 'user_id' in my table. Help me Nikos

Comment: @365Techsolutions, updated answer, let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: Later solved it. Thank you very much for your answers, that has really helped me to some level. Later discovered I was using this smaller version of created post. This This line of code was the problem $request->user()->posts()->create($request->all());